# Activiti 6:Add new task instance to multi instance sub task or multi instance sub process at runtime

Tags: activiti

How can we achieve creation of a new user task instance to multi sub process process or multi instance user task at run time.

For example, Process is started and with multi instance user task lets say 3 user task instance is created and now user want to add one more task to that multi instance sub process instace or multi instance user task so that total user task will be 4 for that multi instance activiti.

Any help will be really apprreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a relatively common request.
For example, reviewing contracts or legal documents. You may want to dynamically add reviewers.
Now, the short answer to dynamically adding instances to a multi instance loop AFTER the instance step has started is, you can't.
However, if you re-architect your solution to have the multi-instance implementation simply signal for a new sub process that represents the "review" then you can have other sub processes signal themselves to initiate a new review.
Obviously on completion or each review you need to "signal completion" so you know when to move on.
Due to it's decoupled nature, this pattern has advantages when it comes to maintenance and updates of the process and associated sub processes.